# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request when trying execute AddMessageAsync()

Tags: c#, azure, queue, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I am facing a problem with Azure Web job while trying to insert a message in Webjob from another project. Not much help found in github issues. confused about what is wrong. my code is as follows:

```
var queueClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("SendReminderEmail");
        var aClassObject = new AModel()
        {
            ObjectName1 = p1,
            ObjectName2 = p2
        };
        var message= new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aClassObject ));
        **await queue.AddMessageAsync(message);** error triggers here
```

json output of message:

> {"stringKey":"value1","intKey":intValue}

this is how queue object looks like: 
[image]

this is the stack trace i am having:

> Error: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request.","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult
>   result) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   50\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndAddMessage(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line
>   1370\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line
>   114\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   WebCruiter.Candidate.Web.Services.AzureQueueService.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\Projects\WebCruiterRepo\Webcruiter\WeCandidate\WebCruiter.Candidate.Web\Services\AzureQueueService.cs:line
>   31\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   WebCruiter.Candidate.Web.Controllers.Api.JobApplicationController.d__45.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\Projects\WebCruiterRepo\Webcruiter\WeCandidate\WebCruiter.Candidate.Web\Controllers\Api\JobApplicationController.cs:line
>   1538\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   WebCruiter.Candidate.Web.Controllers.Api.JobApplicationController.d__18.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\Projects\WebCruiterRepo\Webcruiter\WeCandidate\WebCruiter.Candidate.Web\Controllers\Api\JobApplicationController.cs:line
>   371\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an
>   error: (400) Bad
>   Request.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":"
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode
>   expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal,
>   StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line
>   50\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.b__31(RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line
>   2602\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult
>   getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   299"}}

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aClassObject )`?

Comment: sure i can do it :)

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, I believe you're getting the error in this line of code `queue.CreateIfNotExists();`. Please add the following information as well when editing the question: 1) Actual name of the queue. 2) Storage account type and redundancy level.

Comment: yes, you are right, that's why removed that. should i use CreateIfNotExists(). because in my azure explorer, i can see it is created.

Comment: changed the description

Comment: Your queue name is invalid. It should be all lowercase. Can you please try with that?

Comment: ok trying that right away

Comment: it worked. can you post it as an answer. so that i can reward your.. thanks gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the issue is with the name of queue you're using (`SendReminderEmail`). It should be all lowercase (`sendreminderemail`). For a complete list of naming rules for a queue, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-queues-and-metadata.

Furthermore, may I recommend that you store the messages by converting them to a base64 encoded string. The reason I say this is because the message body should be XML safe. Just in case your message body contains invalid characters like `<`, `>`, `&` etc. your message will not be added to the queue.